# How to weight factors in my model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, weighted-data

Imagine my dataset consists of three factors relating to, as an example, gross domestic product. I want to create a model estimating GDP given a percentage weighting of each factor.

If my three factors were the number of deck chairs, total honey consumption, and stock market value then I would want an estimate based on a model which, for example, gave a 50% weighting to deck chairs and 25% to the other two factors.

One thought that I had was standardising, multiplying by x%, and adding up to create a new "composite" variable. However, I have no formal stats training and am unsure what the downsides of this solution would be. In other words, I want to know why a certain solution is a good idea too.

The application, if it helps, is a consumer-facing data service. I want my customers to create their own models using their own weights/hypothesis about the data.

Comment: This sounds like you have some equations and some unknowns.  You have $GDP = f \left(chairs, honey, stock \right)$.  Algebra says that in order to get a system that is not under-defined, you should have at least as many equations as unknowns.  This suggests you need multiple rows of data that contain GDP, chairs, honey, and or stock.  There are four variables so without at least four equations the system is under-defined and cannot be resolved.  The real world is noisy, so working with only one sample or only with the mean is error rich.  Having excessive samples can enable error reduction.

Comment: You are right. I had difficultly succinctly explaining my actual data but my example doesn't make sense. Apologies. So assume that I do have multiple rows of data and I want to know how well GDP is explained by a 0.5/0.25/0.25 model. I didn't specify my aim well enough either: I want to show the user how well that hypothetical model has explained GDP in the past.

Comment: There are a number of approaches to "how well" estimates.  When starting out, especially when comparing models against the same data, I like to use the AIC or AICc.  I think that you need to be a little meticulous about what "how well ... explained" is thought out.  "Best" (aka "how well") doesn't exist without a "measure of goodness" or a rubric.  MSE (variance + bias^2) and R^2 can also be some initial-use estimators.  Be careful about approaching the problem here.  Think through "why".  Do it because the estimator is informative and not because "some guy on the internet said so".  ;)

Comment: Thanks. And the best way to construct a model that takes percentage weights as an input would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "first stab".  Standard disclaimers apply.

Here is a simulation:

```
#make data

#reproducibility
set.seed(230676)

#rows of data
N <- 80  #years of GDP

#Simulated inputs
chairs <- rpois(n=N, lambda = 12)
honey  <- rnorm(n=N, mean=1, sd = 0.1)
stock  <- cumsum(rnorm(n=N, mean=500, sd=500))+ 10000

#Simulated "TRUE" Model because I don't have actual data
#   I pretend not to know the 0.01, 0.1, 1.0 terms
temp <- 0.01*chairs + 0.1*honey + 1.0*stock
epsilon <- rnorm(n=N, mean=mean(temp), sd=sd(temp))/5

#add some noise
GDP <- temp + epsilon

#least squares fit of raw data
est1 <- lm(GDP~chairs+honey+stock)

summary(est1)
```

My results for the "summary" are:

```
> summary(est1)

Call:
lm(formula = GDP ~ chairs + honey + stock)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
 -8079  -1920    163   1799   6914 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 8574.1175  3353.9718   2.556   0.0126 *  
chairs      -208.0676    95.3243  -2.183   0.0321 *  
honey        -62.6255  3264.2498  -0.019   0.9847    
stock          1.0186     0.0241  42.267   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2695 on 76 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9626,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9611 
F-statistic: 651.1 on 3 and 76 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So the 'R' tool gives some measure of "importance" through "t-value", Pr(>|t|), Residual standard error, Multiple R^2, F-statistic, and p-value.

Those are mouthfuls, but each has a meaning.  Study them to get a sense of what a "101" sort of tool primarily developed by statistics grad students think is important.

The R^2 around 96% suggests that when you use this linear model and compare the errors to a model comprised of only a single constant (the average),  then this linear model has typical error that is about 25x smaller than the typical error for using only the average.

Also - there was something hidden inside the "stock".  That added constant became an "intercept".  Try changing the stock so that it does not have 10,000 added to it, and see what that does to the coefficients.  If you add "+0" to the linear model it changes how this is handled.  One good lesson here is to be careful about how you specify your model because unexpected things can come out of tools if you aren't careful.

Another way to look at the data is EDA ([NIST link](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda34.htm)).  One very basic approach is an array of [scatter plots](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/scatterp.htm), one for each interaction.

Here is the code:

```
#load the library (you may have to install it)
library(psych)

#make the plot (using data above)
pairs.panels(data.frame(GDP,chairs,honey,stock))
```

My result from this is:
[image]

The left column of sub-plots shows the interaction of GDP with the various inputs.  You can see there is a stronger linear relation with "stock" in the lower left corner.  The red line is a line and the correlation coefficient (upper right corner) is also very high.

One thing you see here is that when the coefficient of an effect, like chairs, is small then noises can wash it out.  We know it is really in there somewhere, but the "epsilon", the real world random noise, washed it out.

This is really a very early starting point for looking at the relationship between inputs and outputs.

So here is use of AIC or sample size corrected AICc to pick the better model given constant input data.

```
GDP2 <- 0.25*chairs + 0.25*honey + 0.5*stock

RSS1 <- sum((predict(est1) - GDP)^2)
k1 <- 3  #number of parameters
n1 <- N  #number of samples

AIC1 <- 2*k1 + n1*log(RSS1/n1)
AICc1 <- AIC1 +(2*k1*(k1+1))/(n1-k1-1)


RSS2 <- sum( (GDP2 - GDP)^2)

k2 <- 1  #number of parameters
n2 <- N  #number of samples

AIC2 <- 2*k2 + n2*log(RSS2/n2)
AICc2 <- AIC2 +(2*k2*(k2+1))/(n2-k2-1)

print(c(AIC1,AICc1))
print(c(AIC2,AICc2))
```

For this my result is:

```
> print(c(AIC1,AICc1))
[1] 1265.751 1266.067

> print(c(AIC2,AICc2))
[1] 1622.278 1622.330
```

Both AIC1 and AICC1 are lower than AIC2 and AICc2 respectively, therefore I would suggest that the model 1 (the least squares fit) is initially preferred.

There are truckloads of disclaimers, but here is a decent starter reference for AIC or AICc use in this case.  ([link1](http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/biol548/lecturepdf/08.Modelselection.pdf), [link2](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~shu3/Presentation/AIC.pdf))  There is a great point on page 25 of link1, you should check that out.